# Изменение CancelButton формы в DesignMode другим элементом на ней

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть некоторый контрол:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public Button buttonExit;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Controls.Add(buttonExit = new Button() { Text = "Exit" });
        buttonExit.Click += (s, e) => { (s as Control).FindForm().DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; };
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);

        Form f = FindForm();
        if (f!= null) f.CancelButton = buttonExit;
    }
}
```

Т.е. форма должна получить buttonExit в качестве кнопки закрытия по Esc

В дизайнере кидаю UserControl1 на форму. CancelButton этой формы все равно остался (none)

Подскажите, куда копать

Comment: Посмотрите при отладке в каком экземпляре вы меняете (см. Name). Я так понимаю вы меняете свойство у экземпляра а не у класса.

Comment: @AlexsandrTer не очень понял Ваш комментарий. Как запустить отладку, если работаю в дизайнере VisualStudio? Да, свойство должно поменяться у экземпляра формы - родительской формы этого UserControl'а